# Builder pattern: Do all builder return the same type ?

Tags: design-patterns, builder

In the Builder pattern, do all the concrete builder return the same type of object (with each object having different attributes) OR do they builders each return a sublcass of some other class?

For example, in a car builder, would the builders all return car objects 
or would builders return objects of types such as "luxurycar", "economyCar", "sportsCar" which all inherit from car? If the latter case is correct, then how does the builder add unique attributes to the subclass objects that it creates?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the Builder and Abstract Factory Patterns and make a Builder that can return different types.  I do it all the time.

It's not even limited to subclasses, there is no reason why your builder's build() method can't return  an interface.  This would could lead to each call to `build()` returning different implementations of that interface depending on the builder configuration set through method calls.

example:

```
public interface MyInterface{
  ...
}

public class MyBuilder{
     //builder methods to set values 
     //and configurations to figureout what KIND
     // of MyInterface implementation to build
     ...
     public MyInterface build(){
         if (data can fit in memory){ 
            return new BasicImpl( ...);
         }
         if(can't fit all in memory){
            return new ProxyImpl(...);
         }
          ... etc

     }
}
```

EDIT: using your car example:

```
 public interface Car{

 }


 public class CarBuilder{

      Builder engine(EngineType engine){
          //set the engine type
          return this;
      }

      Builder numberOfPassengers(int n){
          ...
          return this;
      }
      Builder interior(Color color, InteriorType type){
          //interior type is leather, cloth etc
          return this;
      }
      ...
      public Car build(){
          if(is a sporty type of engine, and can only fit a few people){
             return new  SportsCar(....);
          }
          if(has expensive options set and is not a sports car){
              return new LuxuryCar(....);
          }
           .... etc
      }

 }
```

To answer your other question:  How does the builder add unique attributes to the subclass objects, the answer is it has to know all about the subclass attributes and allow the user to set them.  You can add runtime checks to make sure the attributes are only set correctly for the specific subclasses to be returned.  (you can either fail fast and throw IllegalStateException or something in the setter method or wait until `build()` in case the user unsets it later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the classical Builder Pattern from the Gang of Four book, generally it returns a Product. There's no reason that you couldn't build different types, but since you would be returning the item through the base class, the specialization would have to be accessed after a cast or instance of.

If you want to simply support the idea of constructing different types of cars based on different options, etc., Factory Method is probably a better match.

If you are doing a Fluent Interface Builder, subtypes are going to be a drag because you are chaining calls.

In general, Builder is applicable when construction involves distinct operations. The Director knows how to manipulate the Builders to get the product built. You can have the Director have special knowledge about different types. The whole idea is that the Director is masking construction details from the consumer of the Product.

Comment: in the classical pattern, is the "Product" a single class? (i.e do all products belong to the same class)

Comment: Yes. Consider something like car. The Builder will have a private member, and then a method called, say, getCar() that will return it. The idea is if you have to put the engine in, add the wheels, etc., those are methods on the Builder that are invoked as part of a construction protocol, and the get product method is called last to return the result of the construction efforts.